# Setting Up Dynamic Redirects upon User registration/login - Joomla

Tags: joomla3.0

I'm not sure if this is possible at all but this is what I want to acheive:

The website I am working on for a martial arts school.I have program pages that give general info on them. Then I have a link that says 'register to view available times' (for a free trial).

I am wondering how to get the user to the specific page for that program's registration. After that, I want to apply the same sort of thing to each program page. E.g. If I am on kids classes > Register > Redirect to Kids Class Times
Womens > Register > Redirect to Women's Class Times.

Also, want the same thing to happen for a 'login' function.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla natively does not support this. You will have to use a third party extension to achieve this. I have used Community Builder (https://www.joomlapolis.com/) before that is both free and open-source that can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question you like to put some content in to view only for person who is registered on your website.
Here is how to.
1. Create menu item in menu manager > 
Add content to your menu. ( modules , articles ) > . 
Set the same menu item from Public to Registered. 
Button to do so, will be on right side tab: " Details " in menu setting.

2.Then you create a link to these menu or item alias which is public. When the person will click on link the joomla will ask for login and redirect to the menu page.

Hope this helps.